# NProgress is not defined in Vue router

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, vue-nprogress

app.js

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#wrapper',
    router,
    store
});
```

router.js

```
  const router = new VueRouter({
    routes,
    hashbang: false,
    mode: 'history',

})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    NProgress.start()
    NProgress.set(0.1)
    next()
})
router.afterEach(() => {
    setTimeout(() => NProgress.done(), 500)
})
```

Error

```
NProgress is not defined
```

I have already installed `vue-nprogress` using npm still it's showing undefined. How to solve this issue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import and use the plugin in the main.js file as follows:

```
...

import NProgress from 'vue-nprogress'

 
Vue.use(NProgress)
 
const nprogress = new NProgress()
 
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#wrapper',
    router,
    store,
    nprogress
});
```

then in router.js access to that instance using `router.app.$nprogress` :

```
 const router = new VueRouter({
    routes,
    hashbang: false,
    mode: 'history',

})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    router.app.$nprogress.start()
    router.app.$nprogress.set(0.1)
    next()
})
router.afterEach(() => {
    setTimeout(() => router.app.$nprogress.done(), 500)
})
```